# Letting server restart after crash

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I usually let my process manager restart my app when it crashes.

However, I just encountered error handling in Express:

```
app.use( (err,req,res,next) => {
  console.log(err.stack);
  res.status(500).send({"Error" : err.stack});
});
```

I always assumed the app to be in a corrupt state after crash and thus should be restarted.

When an Express app crashes, is it ever a better idea to let the process manager restart the app than to handle the error like the code above?

Answer (score 1):

No, your app is not in the incorrect state and you need to handle your errors in any applications properly. When you restart your app you just swallow an error.

Let me show you the example:

1. User submit post form
2. An error happened in controller that handle this request.
3. Instead of showing 500 for the user you just restart the app

And this will continue again and again. So I think it doesn't make any sense to restart app on any error.

About process managers:
Process manager does restart app on critical errors which kill the processes of nodejs. Without these restarts your whole app wouldn't work. 
Also I highly recommend your to add logger to your app. It could write logs to file and your could track the history of your errors. [Winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston) and [Debug](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug) are good ones.